# LACP bond seems to be favouring one interface when multiple concurrent processes are transferring data

Tags: networking, bonding, lacp

This is likely a really easy one (ie I've fundamentally missed something and its just my fault / lack of knowledge / assumptions).

So I have a machine with 2x 25GbE fibres bonded into bond0 via LACP (cisco switches) with two VLANs.

When I start 5 or 6 concurrent rsyncs transferring different data from one source to a destination path I was slightly surprised to see the data basically favouring one physical interface almost exclusively (~900MiB/s). I was under the assumption that the load would have been somewhat split between the two interfaces that constitute the bond. [image: image of Grafana graph showing network traffic per interface]

I am fully aware that packets are NOT split across interfaces for a single stream, but as my rsync's are all separate processes I would have expected at least one, or two to use the 2nd physical interface....

for reference a 'rough' outline (ie removed info I think is sensitive) of the netplan config in use:

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
  eno1:
   dhcp4: false
   dhcp6: false
   optional: true
   link-local: []
  ens5f0np0:
   dhcp4: false
   dhcp6: false
   optional: true
  ens5f1np1:
   dhcp4: false
   dhcp6: false
   optional: true   
 bonds:
  bond0:
   dhcp4: false
   dhcp6: false
   interfaces: [ens5f0np0, ens5f1np1]
   mtu: 9000
   parameters:
    mode: 802.3ad
    lacp-rate: fast
    mii-monitor-interval: 100
 vlans:
  bond0.xxx:
   id: xxx
   link: bond0
   addresses: [ip]
   gateway4: ip
   mtu: 1500
   nameservers:
    search: [domains]
    addresses: [ips]
  bond0.xxx:
   id: xxx
   link: bond0
   addresses: [ip]
   mtu: 9000
   routes:
   - to: random subnet
     via: local subnet ip
   - to: random subnet
     via: local subnet ip
   - to: random subnet
     via: local subnet ip
```

Is the issue that although the rsync are different processes, the source and destination IPs are the same (each rsync is reading a large sub-folder in one location, and copying to a common location)and the hashing being done at the bond basically means it sees it all as the same traffic? The source data lives on a server in 1 VLAN, and the destination server is on the other.

If it is my fault / improper assumptions would still like to learn all the same as I would have thought the different rsyncs would constitute a different 'stream' of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [LACP](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/bonding.rst?h=v5.15#n614) will use the layer 2 XOR [policy](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/bonding.rst?h=v5.15#n864):

> Slave selection for outgoing traffic is done according to the transmit
> hash policy, which may be changed from the **default simple XOR policy**
> via the `xmit_hash_policy` option, documented below.

> layer2
>
> Uses XOR of hardware MAC addresses and packet type ID field to
> generate the hash. The formula is
>
> hash = source MAC XOR destination MAC XOR packet type ID
> slave number = hash modulo slave count
>
> **This algorithm will place all traffic to a particular
> network peer on the same slave**.

With the default `layer2` or also with the `layer2+3` settings between peer systems using each a single IP address, traffic from the single source IP address resolving to a single source MAC address to the single destination IP address resolving to a single destination MAC address will always hash to the same interface.

You should use the [`layer3+4`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/bonding.rst?h=v5.15#n911) algorithm which will include port in the calculation of the interface:

> layer3+4
>
> This policy uses upper layer protocol information, when available, to
> generate the hash. **This allows for traffic to a particular network
> peer to span multiple slaves**, although a single connection will not
> span multiple slaves.

`ip link`'s `xmit_hash_policy` option translates into *netplan*'s [`transmit_hash_policy`](https://manpages.debian.org/netplan.io/netplan.5#transmit_hash_policy) parameter. So you should add in the configuration this additional parameter:

```
    transmit_hash_policy: layer3+4
```

If traffic were to be tunneled to the same destination's single address, `encap3+4` could be considered instead.

More attention is needed with [this policy](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/bonding.rst?h=v5.15#n911) because it's not fully LACP compliant in case of fragmentation. Because the layer4's protocol (TCP/UDP...) port isn't included in the fragment, this could make first fragment and following fragments use a different interface and have the connection suffer from unwanted packet reordering at the arrival. As long as all involved systems have the same MTU (9000) this shouldn't be a problem since TCP tries to avoid fragmentation:

> This algorithm is not fully 802.3ad compliant.  A single TCP or UDP
> conversation containing both fragmented and unfragmented packets will
> see packets striped across two interfaces.  This may result in out of
> order delivery.   [...]